# how does React access to edit the Javascript list?

Tags: reactjs

I was creating 2 part code and I tried to change code in function in React's App.js file but the one of my code didn't work.

---

in App.js file :

my right code  =>

```
 state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
    ],
    otherState: 'some other value',
    showPersons: false
  }

  togglePersonsHandler = () => {
    const doesShow = this.state.showPersons;
    this.setState({
      showPersons: !doesShow
    });
  }
```

Top code is working ,but my problem is in the bottom code . Why doesn't `nTest Change function` access to the `kkk` list?

```
kkk = {
  State: false,
  show: true
}
nTestChange = () => {
  const doesShow = this.kkk.show;
  this.setState({
    show: !doesShow
  });
```

Overall, I need to change the kkk list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is called setState because it does only one thing: setting the state of the component. React doesn't allow any other variables than state inside a component, so trying to initialize `kkk` inside the component will throw an error, like you mentioned.

There is not really a reason not to use state in your case. State gets used to track variables inside a component, and that is exactly what you want to do. If you really don't want to use state, there is another option: using `this`. You can initialize `kkk` inside the constructor of App.js like this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.kkk = {
    state: false,
    show: true
  }
}

nTestChange = () => {
  this.kkk.show = !this.kkk.show;
}
```

You should only use this if you don't want the component to rerender when `kkk` changes. In your case, I would stick with your working example with `state`.

For more info about state, see the official React docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

The official getting started tutorial will also give you a good introduction to React and state management:
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html
https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#an-interactive-component (section about state management)

Comment: hi @xander-berkein. I tested before but I had an error `'kkk' is not defined  no-undef` Please, tell me what is my problem ?

Comment: Hi @shahryartavakkoli. My bad, I forgot to add you can't initiate variables inside a component. I updated the example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` function change only `this.state` object. By the way, another form `setState()` function is:

```
togglePersonsHandler = () => {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    showPersons: !prevState.showPersons
  });
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Thank you @Yura . I still have the problem. I want to update the **kkk** list but I can't.I saw the page before but I didn't understand.

Comment: You must understand, that method `render()` rewrite ui only when `this.state` or `this.props` objects have been changed. If you change any other object, like `this.kkk`, method `render()` does not rewrite ui. Look at my jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/smhfanda/nsmxsaj5/ In console you can see that `this.kkk` was changed, but ui doesn't changed.

Comment: Another words: method `render()` called when `this.state` or `this.props` was changed.

Comment: I understand what you said now,  Thank you for it. Is there any way for using other objects ? I mean to except The `this.state` ?

Comment: Any other objects doesn't have effect